# Use `swagger-ui-express` and `swagger-jsdoc` before and after typescript transpilation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, swagger

Well, basically I am trying to make both packages in the title work in my project that uses typescript, its path mapping and esbuild for transpiling.
Unfortunately, the swagger doesn't work with the transpiled code... To transpile I use `rimraf dist && esbuild ./src/index.ts --target=es2016 --bundle --platform=node --outdir=dist` and to run `node dist/index.js`. The swagger page simply doesn't appear.

code snippets: https://gist.github.com/joaocasarin/167ad9a5feeb564c19e2c92e03619dd7
`src/app.ts`: 1st file

`@docs/v1.ts`: 2nd file

As you see in the 2nd file, I am setting the swagger-jsdoc to read both ts and js files with `apis: ['**/routes/**/*.ts', '**/routes/**/*.js']`, but I know it's wrong, i just don't know how to correct it.

`@routes/user.ts`: 3rd file

When I run the server using `tsx watch --tsconfig ./tsconfig.build.json ./src/index.ts`, it is fine, I can use either swagger page or the endpoints I have.
When I transpile it to javascript, the swagger page doesn't work anymore (maybe because it cannot find the jsdoc setups?

You can see in the picture the errors when I access /docs, which are in the 4th file of the gist
[image: errors console]

How to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem when I added to esbuild option `--external:swagger-ui-express`.